# AngularJS Sortable order pricing issue

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm facing an issue when ordering prices formatted as currency.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.factory("Purchases", function() {
  var Purchases = {};

  Purchases.data = [{
      date: "10/05/2012",
      text: "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
      price: "£90",
      availability: "1 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
    },
    {
      date: "24/05/2012",
      text: "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
      price: "£9.5",
      availability: "2 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
    },
    {
      date: "20/05/2012",
      text: "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
      price: "£10",
      availability: "3 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
    }
  ];
  return Purchases;
});

function PurchasesCtrl($scope, Purchases) {
  $scope.purchases = Purchases;
  $scope.sort = {
    column: '',
    descending: false
  };
  $scope.changeSorting = function(column) {

    var sort = $scope.sort;

    if (sort.column == column) {
      sort.descending = !sort.descending;
    } else {
      sort.column = column;
      sort.descending = false;
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PurchasesCtrl">
    <h2>Purchases:</h2>
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="first">
        <th class="first" ng-click="changeSorting('date')">Date</th>
        <th ng-click="changeSorting('text')">Description</th>
        <th ng-click="changeSorting('price')">Amount</th>
        <th ng-click="changeSorting('availability')">Status</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="purchase in purchases.data|orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending">
        <td class="first">{{purchase.date}}</td>
        <td>{{purchase.text}}</td>
        <td>{{purchase.price}}</td>
        <td>{{purchase.availability}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue order: `$9.5 > $10`
Is there any way to correct the ordering?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code here as well. External links can change or disappear over time and then in future the question might make no sense. You can also make a runnable StackSnippet within this question without needing an external site like JSFiddle to make a demo. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Copied Fiddle to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2u3wn91z/1/ .
You want to compare `number`s, not `string`s, so you need to separate `currency` (as first letter of `price`) and then remove `currency` from `price`):

```
  Purchases.data = Purchases.data.map(function (purchase) {
    purchase.currency = purchase.price.charAt(0);
    purchase.price = Number(purchase.price.substr(1));
    return purchase;
  });
   $scope.purchases = Purchases;
```

When you have price separated from currency, you can display it separately:

```
<td>{{purchase.currency}}{{purchase.price}}</td>
```